# Exploring the locations of monsters in a Minecraft map

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to "debug" my large monster spawning room. I am aware that all surrounding caves must be lit, but my trap still seems to wind down after a few minutes. I would ideally like to use a tool to figure out where the monsters are so that I can light up the remaining areas. Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 3):

If you're okay with using a mod, you can install [zombe's modpack](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/91055-v110-zombes-modpack-26-mods-v510-upd-18jan/). There is a mod called "cheat" in there, and it has a feature that highlights all mobs through walls with a colored marker. Here's what that looks like in-game:

[image: cheat]

It works in multiplayer as well if you need that support.

If you don't like installing mods, you can always use [MCEdit](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/13807-mcedit-minecraft-world-editor-compatible-with-mc-beta-18/) to explore your world, but development has become a bit stagnated, and you'll need to figure out how to compile a dev version to get it to work with MC 1.1.

Comment: MCEdit stable33 works fine with 1.1 — it doesn't know some of the block types, but it can read the world and display entities.

Answer (score 2):

As Jake King said, you could use zombe's modpack, but I think your asking for a different part of it:

[image]

Its the safe mod, and the red cross hatch area is where monsters can spawn.

Comment: Good tip, but I think my answer is correct. He doesn't know where the monsters are spawning, since he can't find the monsters. This will show him where they can spawn, but I think he believes they're spawning in adjacent caves unbeknownst to him.